# Which SQLite operator is used for pattern matching?

Tags: sqlite

I can use LIKE to find an occurance of a pattern in a table if the table has rows (red, redd, dred, green), like

```
WHERE column LIKE '%red%'
```

will return (red, redd, dred).

Is there any operator for the opposite matching?

```
WHERE column OPERATOR 'green, blue, yellow'
```

should return (green)

Comment: My only experience with sqlite is through the python module so ymmv, but there is a REGEXP function that lets you use regular expressions to perform matching.  For the python implementation you have to 'hook it up' to a real function – I don't know whether that holds for other implementations.  Here's how you would go about making the regexp function in python:   https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function

Comment: `should return (green)` is not the **opposite matching**. The **opposite matching** is `NOT Like '%red%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something like this:

```
... WHERE MyColumn IN ('green', 'blue', 'yellow')
```

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a string occurs as a substring in another string, use LIKE.

In this case, the substring is the column value, so you have to put it on the other side. Additionally, you need to add the pattern characters:

```
... WHERE 'green,blue,yellow' LIKE '%' || MyColumn || '%' ...
```